# Modify production Google App Engine Java project without using IDE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an existing Google App Engine project, in production, but coded a long while ago (7+ years). The project uses HttpServlet extensively. The various HttpServlet are quite independent and call each other when needed via REST, specifically using Queue (QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue()) and TaskOptions (TaskOptions.Builder). The Servlet that sends email looks like this:

```
public class MySendEmailServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to make small changes to the code. Updating the text, changing certain values etc. But when I launch my IDE (last time was 3 years ago), it blows up with 1000+ warnings. I really don't feel like fixing the whole environment, just for small changes. Is there another way to approach this? For example, can I compile the Java files for the Servlet I need to update (using javac), and (somehow) update it directly via Google Cloud console? I am even OK with using Python, and migrating the code, if it will allow for such incremental updates. Thank you.